# How to create TS segment on demand if M3U8 playlist is given

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, http-live-streaming, ffmpeg-php

While transcoding I have to create m3u8 playlist manually and now on-demand I want to create .ts files. I have used FFmpeg's cut option from start to end but .ts files have audio problems while getting played.

I have a command which creates ts files as well as m3u8.

```
 ffmpeg -i input -g 10 -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 0  out.m3u8
```

But as I said out.m3u8 I already have and the above command takes time to generate all ts files. Is there any other command in which I can generate one ts file when the start and end are given?

I have tried commands below:

```
ffmpeg -i input -acodec aac -vcodec h264 -ss 0 -to 3 chunk1.ts
ffmpeg -i input -acodec aac -vcodec h264 -ss 3 -to 6 chunk2.ts
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible with ffmpeg, or any existing software. AAC has something called priming samples that prevent concatenation from working properly.

Comment: I am new to FFmpeg, what would you suggest? Should we always create chunks alongside m3u8 file?

Comment: Either transcode once in advance, like ffmpeg was designed to do.  Or study the acc specification and develop a custom tool that can satisfy the requirement for bitstream concatenation.